# Is there a way to do automation of voice verification in iOS device using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, voice, ios-ui-automation

I have an app that throws out some pre-recorded voice messages on performing some tasks. For simplicity, consider I have button and on clicking it, it says "You clicked a button".

My question is can we automate this verification process?? can we do this by comparing it with existing .mp3 files or by any other method???

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by verification process?

Comment: I meant, can we compare the voice message produced by iOS device and stored voice message ( may be in .mp3 file ) and come to conclusion that both are same. If it turns out be same we can pass the test case.

Comment: Technically yes, but not easily. See the 'UIAHost.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout' function. If you run your app through the simulator you can trigger and external script to listen to the output and then compare the two. I don't think it will be possible to do this inside of the instrument though.